# Make fancyhdr reproduce exactly the standard configuration

Tags: fancyhdr

Which arguments make `fancyhdr` reproduce **exactly** the standard page layout when using the `book` document class?

The standard layout of `fancyhdr` introduces upper and lower bars, it capitalizes the names of sections and chapters, it adds 'Chapter' in front of every chapter number in the headings, and changes the section counter to something like 'III.4' instead of '4'. This all comes in as noise if you just want to move the page number to the center bottom.

Comment: A simple remark: as far as I know, the `book` class capitalises chapter and section titles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Uppercase and number formatting is already the same using page style `headings` of class `book`:

[image: book default]

or page style `fancy` of `fancyhdr`. Nevertheless, the headings themself are different, because `fancyhdr`'s default uses `\leftmark` and `\rightmark` on every page, which is very uncommon. You can change this using, e.g., `\fancyhead`. If you also want the page number at the outer margin, you may also use `\fancyfoot` to change the page footer. If you also want to remove the rule below the head, you can set `\headrulewidth` to 0pt. So you get something like:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead[RE]{\slshape\leftmark}% right even head with chapter mark
\fancyhead[LO]{\slshape\rightmark}% left odd head with section mark
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{}% remove left even and right odd head
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}% set left even and right odd foot
\fancyfoot[C]{}% remove centre foot
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Note: It's a command not a length!
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image: slanted fancyhdr]

Another approach would be to use `scrlayer-scrpage` instead of `fancyhdr`. This package does not change the default of `book`. So to move the page number into the foot, you only have to remove it from the head and put it into the foot:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\ohead{}% remove page number from head
\ofoot*{\pagemark}% put page number into the foot (also at plain pages)
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as above.

If you don't want uppercase headings, you can use:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[markcase=noupper,automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\ohead{}% remove page number from head
\ofoot*{\pagemark}% put page number into the foot (also at plain pages)
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image: scrlayer-scrpage with mixed case]

If you really want the page number centered:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[markcase=noupper,automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\ohead{}% remove page number from head
\cfoot*{\pagemark}% add page number at the centre
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Nevertheless, for twoside documents I would prefer the headings and the page number at the outer margin:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[pagestyleset=KOMA-Script,markcase=noupper,automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

And if you want to remove the `Chapter` from the running head, you can use:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[pagestyleset=KOMA-Script,markcase=noupper,automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{\thechapter.\enskip}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you really want to preserve the standard headings of the `book` class, you don't need `fancyhdr`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@evenhead{\hfil\slshape\leftmark}
\renewcommand\@oddhead{\slshape\rightmark\hfil}
\renewcommand\@evenfoot{\hfil\thepage\hfil}
\renewcommand\@oddfoot{\hfil\thepage\hfil}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

With `fancyhdr`:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all fields
\fancyhead[RE]{\slshape\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{\slshape\rightmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
% restore the standard \chaptermark and \sectionmark
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{%
  \markboth{%
    \MakeUppercase{%
      \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \if@mainmatter
          \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ %
        \fi
      \fi
      #1%
    }%
  }{}%
}
\renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{%
  \markright{%
    \MakeUppercase{%
      \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\z@
        \thesection. \ %
      \fi
      #1%
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother
```

You may need to also set `\headheight` if you use the `11pt` or `12pt` class options: look at the log file for the warning issued by `fancyhdr` about it.

I have no doubt which method to prefer.